# Plot multiple lines in one go

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I would like to plot multiple lines on the same graph in matlab. I cant't find the easiest way to do it. At the moment I have something like this:

```
for j=1:n
plot(j,total,'*')
hold on
end
```

`total` changes in each iteration as well as `j`. This will make the plot I want but with the '*' instead of lines. I would like to join these asterisk with a line for each colour. Keep in mind that `total` is a vector with length `k`, thus in each iteration i have `k` asterisks.

For example:

iteration 1: j=1, total= [ 0.2000 0.6000 0.2000]'

iteration 2: j=2, total= [0.1000 0.6000 0.3000]'

iteration 3: j=3, total= [0.2095 0.4476 0.3429]'

X-axis is 1,2,3 and Y-axis should have 0.2,0.1,0.2095 connected with a line and an asterisks at these points, 0.6,0.6,0.4476 connected with a different colour line and asterisk etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want a different color for each line. In that case, I suggest:

```
figure
hold all
for j=1:n
    plot(j,total,'-*')
end
```

For the difference between `hold all` and `hold on` see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html

The information about how to specify line styles is here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html

Based on the additional information about the data, sample code is:

```
nData = 3;
dataset = zeros(n,nData);
for j = 1:n
    dataset(j,:) = total';
end

x = 1:n;
plot(x,dataset,'-*');
legend('data set 1','data set 2','data set 3')
```

In this case `hold` is not required because all the data is plotted at once.

Comment: it didnt serve the purpose. I added an example to the description to be more clear. Your method just adds even more colours and still no line whatsoever.

Comment: You need to use plot(j*ones(size(total)),total,'-*') to get lines.

Comment: I should have noticed when writing that it doesn't make sense to have the `x`  values in the `plot` command be the loop counter `j`. For your problem, you need to save the data to separate vectors (or a matrix) first then plot it.

Comment: What was the difference between "hold all" and "hold on"? The only difference now is that "hold all" is deprecated...

Comment: @durka42 With `hold on` the color and line styles were reset, while with `hold all` the sequence of colors and styles would continue.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to use lower level functions. Set up some axes and then generate a new line object (this is usually faster than recalling plot) on each iteration. The code below will generate a new line on the same set of axes for each iteration, coloring progressively from blue to red. I'm assuming that you can generate XVec from j each time:

```
myAx = axes;
for j=1:n
lineCol = [(j-1)/(n-1) 0 (1-((j-1)/(n-1)))];
line('XData',XVec(j,:),'YData',total,'color',lineCol,'linestyle','-','marker','*','Parent','myAx');
end
```

This removes the need for the `hold` command.

Comment: what is XVec? j is just a counter

Comment: `XVec` is just some array, size n x k, which describes the x-locations of your data - for each 1 x k vector of data, you need 1 x k x-locations.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
plot(j,total,'-*');
```

The `-` before the `*` means use a line AND an asterisk.

Also, it would be neater to put the `hold on` before the start of the loop, since you only need it once.

Answer (score 0):

Put all data as columns in a matrix:

```
j = 1:5;

data1 = [1 2 3 4 5];
data2 = [5 4 3 2 1];
data3 = [4 6 2 8 3];

y = [ data1; data2; data3 ].';
plot(j,y)
```

This automatically sets different colors for each line